# How to get different columns from different table in single join in gorm

Tags: mysql, go, join, select, go-gorm

Hi I have 2 tables companies and user. (user_id is foreign key in companies table).
I want to get company details of all users holding a particular phone number.(phone number is present in user table).
For that I am executing gorm query like that
`*gorm.db.Table("companies").Joins("inner join users ON companies.user_id = users.id AND users.phone_number IN (?)",['1234'.'3456']).Find(&out)`

Here is out is my struct that contains all columns of companies table along with that I added a field phone_number which is from users table.
My problem is I am getting all data of companies table in out but I am not getting phone_number in out as it os from users table.

I can do this by selecting all columns of companies table and phone number of users table in select() , but as companies have 50 columns so it has very tough task to do.

Can anyone help me to achieve this in a single query without selecting all columns by its name.
I want Gorm query as I am writing this in Golang.

Comment: I think you may want to think about using Preload
https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html